# Spring Controller Advice Exception Handler always Returning 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception, http-status-code-404

The @ExceptionHandler returns a 200 response with a MyResponse object when called within the controller, but when it is called from ControllerAdvice it returns 404 with a generic 404 message.
I want it to return a 200 response with a MyResponse object.

My code for exception handling below, both in the Controller and ControllerAdvice. I commented it out in the Controller when testing ControllerAdvice. Debugging showed the method being called in the ControllerAdvice after commenting out in the controller

> ```
> @ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)
>      public MyResponse handleMyException(HttpServletRequest req, MyException e) {
>     return new MyResponse(MyResponse.ERROR_CODE, e.getErrorCode(), e.getMessage(), "", null);
> }
> ```

Below is how I define my ControllerAdvice.

> ```
> @EnableWebMvc 
> @ControllerAdvice 
> @ResponseStatus(value= HttpStatus.OK)
> public class ControllerAdviceExceptionHandler {
> ```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was that my exception handler needed the `@ResponseBody` annotation. 
My controller did this implicitly in Spring but I had to specify it externally.

Sidenote: I had to remove the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation for my junit tests to work as I was initialising the context elsewhere in my test configurations (even though everything worked perfectly when the server was running)

Comment: what if i need to return a page in exception handler?